# Do I need to close connection in Gorm?

Tags: mysql, database, go, go-gorm

I have added .raw() SQL query in my program, and found this function cause Nginx error:110 connection timeout, so I am wondering if I suppose to close the connection every time I execute a SQL query.

```
func AddRecordErrorLog(id uint, recordtable *Recordtable, record map[string]interface{}) {

    instance, err := db.GetDBInstance()
    instance.Gorm().Raw("UPDATE `testDB`.`recordtable` SET `log` = '", record, "' WHERE id =?", id).Scan(&attendence)
}
```

Comment: Depends, is there is a connection to be closed? What does `GetDBInstance()` and `Gorm()` do? Are one of them opening a new connection each time they are invoked or are they using some cache? If the former, then yes, please do close the connection every single time! If you don't want to do that because you think its tedious, and I would agree, then you should start reusing the connection instead of always creating new one.

Comment: thanks for replying, the GetDBInstance() and Gorm() are used to create connections and occupy a connection from connection pool, and I have no idea how to close a connection in Gorm, are there and related link? @mkopriva

Comment: If you call `DB()` on the gorm instance (https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.DB), you can get the raw sql.DB object, which has a close() function on it (https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Close).